# What are those things in text design?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

What are those things? What are they for? How do I enable them?[image]

Comment: ...Hover over them and look it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are [substitution or pre-composed variant](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/fonts.html#about_missing_fonts_and_glyph_protection) that are alternate glyphs and may not be available on all fonts; you will see them only when the font was created to incorporate them in a specific way.

**Example from Myriad Pro Bold from the Typekit:**

Top example is without using the "Fraction" substitution, bottom example is using it.

[image: example different font substitution]

You can't really enable them if the font doesn't have these substitutions included already in their set. They will be accessible only for certain fonts. You'll find them on [Open-Type fonts](http://www.adobe.com/products/type/opentype.html).

If they are available, you can enable or disable them by clicking on the icon.

[image: Example of glyphs]

There's also fonts that include these substitutions but they might be part of another font family named differently and won't be available on this small Character menu. They're not as convenient to use as the option above. For example, the Helvetica Fractions.

[image: Helvetica Fractions]

Comment: Could you tell me one font that has this resources?

Comment: If you look at the image @go-me posted you'll see at least one example of such a font :)

Comment: @JohnSmith it's hard to find a font that has all these substitutions available but lot of the fonts from the TypeKit , Apple system fonts or very classical ones have some of them.

Comment: House Industries produces some wonderful fonts with these features. You can preview them on their website, here's one I'd like to buy: http://www.houseind.com/fonts/eames ---- click "More Options" by the Text to Set panel.